# I have selected an answer, but my requirements have changed

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, edits, asking-questions

I recently posted a question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/150329/is-it-possible-to-do-this-math-in-a-view) that garnered a couple nice answers. I selected the best one that worked and went on my merry way. Now, however, my requirements have changed slightly, but enough that the the answer doesn't quite fit.

Is it more appropriate to create another question, and maybe reference the old question or include the bulk of the question that applies? Is it bad to create a near duplicate in this way?

Answer (score 21):

Ask a new (follow-up) question, including a link to the previous one if it provides useful context. The new question should still make sense on its own, of course.

As a *general rule*, it is better to start a new question when a question edit would invalidate good answers.

We don't charge by the question (but please don't go nuts - a hundred similar, very specific questions are not likely to be well received).